# Stacking images for the purpose of a media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

simple question, with a simple answer that I cannot seem to figure out.

I have 12 images in the form of 6 rows and 2 columns that I would like to be formatted to 12 rows with 1 column when my media query breaks to 240 px wide.

This has got to be an incredibly easy positioning solution I am totally missing after 12 hours of working server code, but I can't find the simple solution to fix it.

Here is my markup (the same for all 12 images):

```
<div class="view view-first">
               <img src = "img/img1.jpg" alt="First Image">
               <div class="mask">
               <h2>Displayed 1st Image</h2>
               <p>Image example</p>
               <a href ="img1.html" class="info">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is my markup for all images:

```
.view {

   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
   float: left;
   border: 10px solid #fff;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   cursor: default;
   background: #fff url(../img/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {

   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
.view h2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 17px;
   padding: 10px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.view p {
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow:3px 3px 5px #000;
   padding: 10px 20px 20px;
   text-align: center;
}
.view a.info {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 7px 14px;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
.view a.info: hover {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

I'd show the media query but right now it is just the call and the max-width stipulation lol.

Thanks for the kind help ;)

Comment: I don't get it. Testing your markup, it breaks into a single column when it should. Also, to test, I had to paste your image code 12 times. Will you post a fiddle, please and better describe the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use media-queries you have to use percentages for the width. That way your image will "scale" as you resizes the browser. Two rows with 6 images means each image has a width of 50%. Do note that you have to take in account margins and paddings.

You can simply put in your media query from the size of xxxx give the images width 100%.